# When i am trying to run coomand sudo chef-server-ctl test the following error is coming

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, chef-infra

```
sudo: unable to resolve host mychefserver.example.com
/opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.0.6/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:340: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040757
/opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:211: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040757
/opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:211: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040757
Configuring logging...
Creating platform...
Starting Pedant Run: 2013-10-28 05:50:35 UTC
setting up rspec config for #<Pedant::OpenSourcePlatform:0x00000001952ee0>
Configuring RSpec for Open-Source Tests
```

Comment: That's nice and all, but what is your question? And what have you already tried to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the server can't resolve its hostname mychefserver.example.com